# Debugging minified js on chrome with sourcemap(uglifyjsplugin/webpack)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webpack

I'm writing an application in javascript with webpack2 and i'm having a big problem, when i'm trying to debug the minified code generated by webpack uglify(`webpack -p`), chrome console can't evaluate the variables.

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");
var package = require("./package");

module.exports = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: "./app.js",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
        filename: "app-" + package.version + ".js"
    }
};
```

app.js

```
var firstLetter = "a";
var secondLetter = "b";

teste(firstLetter + secondLetter);

function teste(msg) {
    var msgAlert = msg + "c";
    alert(msgAlert);
}
```

[console evaluate problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTAMq.png)

Is this normal browser behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try devtool: 'inline-source-map', and do webpack without -p just to see full debugging symbols